# Where does aws opsworks deploy to by default?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, aws-opsworks

Let's say we have a laravel app that is deployed from a github repository.

What I can't seem to find any documentation for is where the applications source code is deployed to on the filesystem?

We are using PHP5.5 features in our code so our PHP App Server is a custom layer based off an AMI.

I need to setup an apache vhost that points to the application, but I can't do this if I don't know where it get's deployed to!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

it's usually under the user /srv/www/#{application_shortname}